# DELETE in a REST API without an entity ID best practice

Tags: rest

I have a timespan I want to delete in a REST API.

It doesn't have an id so calling HTTP DELETE on "/timespan/" is not really possible. The implementation would be possible, but I would rather not put in the extra effort (requires some database modifications) unless there is a good reason to add it.

I considered calling DELETE on "/timespan/" with "start" and "end" inside the request but to my understanding this clashes with the way REST works.

Is it legit to call DELETE on "/timespan//" or maybe a concatenation such as "/timespan/+" or should I implement IDs after all?

Comment: How do you know what to delete, if you don't have an ID?

Comment: _What_ are you deleting? Please describe your schema, in order to understand your picture better. Then consider something like `GET /path/to/resource?from={from}&to={to}`, then issue single `DELETE`s on every retrieved id.

Comment: I have a site. Each site can have one maintenance or none at all. When deleting the maintenance i could just delete that max 1 maintenance the site has. But I am afraid users could accidentally delete maintenances they didn't mean to delete so i want to make sure to delete the right maintenance. Is it a good idea to do that without a maintenance ID?

Comment: How do you decice between an intended delete and an accidental one? If the resource has an ID or not is not of relevance. DELETE deletes the resource the URI is pointing at - if the last part of an URI is just `maintenance` but has a field `id` set to `1234` the DELETE should DELETE `/a/b/c/maintenance` where `/a/b/c` is the path containing the parent-resources of `maintenance`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct. DELETE doesn't take a body.

RFC 7231:

> A payload within a DELETE request message has no defined semantics;
>      sending a payload body on a DELETE request might cause some existing
>      implementations to reject the request.

I've seen what you want done as

DELETE /sites/{siteId}/maintenance

but that's really not optimal. If `maintenance` is a resource, it needs some way of being uniquely identified. If it's a property of a resource, then you delete it via `PUT` or `PATCH` on that resource.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your resource is a maintenance performed on a site. The API could have:

- `DELETE /sites/{site-id}/maintenances/{maintenance-id}` to delete one maintenance. **The typical delete**.
- `DELETE /sites/{site-id}/maintenances` to delete all maintenances of a given site. **Not usual, and dangerous.**
- `DELETE /site/{site-id}/maintenances?start={start-date}&end={end-date}` to delete all maintenances in a timespan. **The answer to your question.**

*Rationale*: the timespan is not part of the resource, it's a filtering attribute on the collection of resources. Therefore, it should not be part of the URI (Uniform Resource **Identifier**). We should use [query string parameters for filtering](https://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#advanced-queries).

Another option:

- `POST /site/{site-id}/clean-up` to delete all maintenances of a given site that are within the timespan specified in the request body. **Also an answer to your question.**

*Rationale*: some advocate that a REST API can offer more "coarse-grained" operations that closely resemble the business capability in complement to (or in the place of) more CRUD-like APIs. [Here's a reference](https://www.thoughtworks.com/pt/insights/blog/rest-api-design-resource-modeling). In the particular case, the POST operation executes a "clean-up business process". The start and end dates go in the request body. The operation should return 200 (not 201) for success.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of designing a low-level CRUD-like REST API and let the callers know details about your domain, you could let the client POST their intent and let the server decide what to delete. Seems like the right approach if you ant to prevent users from accidentally (maliciously?) deleting resources. More in *Fine grained CRUD resources versus Coarse Grained resources* at http://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/rest-api-design-resource-modeling

Comment: The link was not completely relevant but a very interesting read nevertheless.

Comment: Glad to hear you liked the link, but I actually see it as quite relevant to your question. You ask: 'How to design DELTE without id, and prevent user from making errors?' The answer this article gives is: 'Don't. Let the client POST their intent, then the server can figure out what to do.'

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the RESTful principle closely, you would need to retrieve a list of resources (partial as proposed by @moonwave99) and invoke `DELETE` on every resource whose timestamp is older than a certain threshold. This conveis the semantics of delete while being completely idempotent. You, however, need a resource identifier therefore (which you should have obtained via the previous retrieve).

The next choice would be to set off a `PUT` request where you send each and every entry that should be available after the request within that request. In practice this is however a no-go as to much data would need to be transfered.

Last but not least, you would have the possibility to delete resources via `PATCH` where you pass the necessary instructions to the server it needs to transform the resource(s) from state_before to state_after. In case of [`json-patch`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) you have the `remove` operation at hand. However, the spec does not provide any possibility to remove a state if a certain condition was met - a combination of test+delete would be handy in that case. The quintesence is though, that not the server is responsible for filtering out certain data but the client which has to send each necessary step to the server. Therefore, a client has to retrieve the current state of a resource collection like `/api/sampleResources` which could be an array of JSON objects and do the decission locally:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
ETag: "7776cdb01f44354af8bfa4db0c56eebcb1378975"
...

[
    {
        ...
        "timestamp": "2015-07-17T19:40:00",
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
        "timestamp": "2014-10-05T10:00:00",
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
        "timestamp": "2015-07-16T15:00:00",
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
        "timestamp": "2014-12-31T00:00:00",
        ...
    }
]
```

If all entries from the last year should be deleted, a JSON-PATCH request would need to look like this:

```
PATCH /api/sampleResources
...
ETag: "7776cdb01f44354af8bfa4db0c56eebcb1378975"
...

[
    { "op": "remove", "path": "/1" },
    { "op": "remove", "path": "/3" }
]
```

The path is specified in [JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) notation and is 0 based, therefore the sample above removes the second and fourth entry of the list, which are the entries of 2014.

As the resource can be modified between the lookup and the patch generation, it is highly recommended to use ETag features to gurantee that the patch is executed on the right state. If the ETags do not match, the request fails with a precondition failure.

Note however, that PATCH is not idempotent! So sending the same request twice may delete more entries as intended. This is not the case with PUT, as the state after the request is exactly the state you told the resource to have. Therefore, sending the same request twice does not change anything state-wise. In comparison to a bunch of `DELETE` requests, `PATCH` is atomic - either all or none of the operations are executed, while the `DELETE` requests are all independent.

I agree strongly, that there is a need for conditional and partial `PUT` and `DELETE` operations to adhere to the business needs. For simplicity reasons I would really recommend to use partial `GET` and `DELETE` operations instead of `PUT` or `PATCH`.